# How can I indent HTML with VBA?

Tags: html, vba, ms-access, indentation, pretty-print

I am generating some HTML in VBA (MSACCESS), which works fine but it is a bit of a mess from an indentation point of view.
Is there an easy way to indent a stream of HTML text in VBA?
I use Visual Studio Code format functionality to have a prettier HTML, but I have to do this by hand and it is very tedious!

Example:

```
<div class="anythinggoes">
<ul><li>A</li>
        <li>B</li><li>C</li>
    </ul></div> <!-- anythinggoes -->
```

Should become something like:

```
<div class="anythinggoes">
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
    </ul>
</div> <!-- anythinggoes -->
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: You are in control, so adjust your generating code to set the indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CAUTION! Ugly code ahead!**

Welcome on board, RichD. I think this code might help you:

First, define these variables in the Module scope:

```
Private InlineTags As Variant
Private InlineClosingTags As Variant
Private LineBreakTags As Variant
```

Then, we can use this function:

```
Function ReadableHTML(HTML As String) As String
    Dim a$, i&, TabsNo&, tabs$, l&, tag$, MaxTabs&

    'add here tags that you want to keep on the same line of their parent
    InlineTags = Array("!--", "a", "i", "b", "sup", "sub", "strong") 'never followed by a line break
    InlineClosingTags = Array("li", "h1", "h2", "h3", "h4") 'always followed by a line break
    LineBreakTags = Array("br", "br/", "br /") 'always lead & followed by a line break

    a = CleanOf(HTML)
    TabsNo = -1
    i = 1
    l = Len(a)
    Do While i < l
        If Mid(a, i, 2) = "</" Then
            tag = Mid(a, i + 2, InStr(i + 2, a, ">") - i - 2)
            If Not IsInArray(tag, InlineClosingTags) Or Mid(a, i - 1, 1) = ">" Then
                tabs = Chr(10) & Filler(TabsNo, Chr(9))
                a = Left(a, i - 1) & tabs & Right(a, Len(a) - i + 1)
                l = Len(a)
                i = i + Len(tabs)
            End If
            TabsNo = TabsNo - 1
        Else
            Select Case Mid(a, i, 1)
            Case "<"
                tag = Mid(a, i + 1, InStr(i + 1, a, ">") - i - 1)
                If Not IsInArray(tag, InlineTags) Then
                    TabsNo = TabsNo + 1
                    If TabsNo > MaxTabs Then MaxTabs = TabsNo
                    If i > 1 Then tabs = Chr(10) & Filler(TabsNo, Chr(9)) Else tabs = Filler(TabsNo, Chr(9))
'                    tabs = tabs & Filler(TabsNo, Chr(9))
                    a = Left(a, i - 1) & tabs & Right(a, Len(a) - i + 1)
                    l = Len(a)
                    i = i + Len(tabs)
                    If IsInArray(tag, LineBreakTags) Then TabsNo = TabsNo - 1
                End If
            Case ">"
                tag = Mid(a, InStrRev(a, "<", i) + 1, i - InStrRev(a, "<", i) - 1)
                If Not IsInArray(tag, InlineClosingTags) Then
                    tabs = Chr(10) & Filler(TabsNo + 1, Chr(9))
                    a = Left(a, i) & tabs & Right(a, Len(a) - i)
                End If
            Case Chr(10)
                If Mid(a, i + 1, 1) <> Chr(9) And Mid(a, i + 1, 1) <> "<" Then
                    tabs = Chr(10) & Filler(TabsNo + 1, Chr(9))
                    a = Left(a, i) & tabs & Right(a, Len(a) - i)
                    l = Len(a)
                    i = i + Len(tabs)
                End If
            End Select
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    For TabsNo = MaxTabs To 0 Step -1
        a = Replace(a, Chr(10) & Filler(TabsNo, Chr(9)) & Chr(10), Chr(10))
    Next
    ReadableHTML = treatInlineTags(a, False)
End Function
```

Which uses these helping functions:

```
Function treatInlineTags(a As String, HideFlag As Boolean)
    'Hides/unhides inline tags from CleanOf
    If HideFlag Then
        For i = LBound(InlineTags) To UBound(InlineTags)
            a = Replace(a, "<" & InlineTags(i) & " ", "|" & InlineTags(i) & "¦")
            a = Replace(a, "<" & InlineTags(i) & ">", "|" & InlineTags(i) & "|")
            a = Replace(a, "</" & InlineTags(i) & ">", "|/" & InlineTags(i) & "|")
        Next i
    Else
        For i = LBound(InlineTags) To UBound(InlineTags)
            a = Replace(a, "|" & InlineTags(i) & "¦", "<" & InlineTags(i) & " ")
            a = Replace(a, "|" & InlineTags(i) & "|", "<" & InlineTags(i) & ">")
            a = Replace(a, "|/" & InlineTags(i) & "|", "</" & InlineTags(i) & ">")
        Next i
    End If
    treatInlineTags = a
End Function

Function IsInArray(a As String, Arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        IsInArray = a = Arr(i)
        If IsInArray Then Exit Function
    Next i
End Function

Function CleanOf(a As String) As String
    'Removes unwanted spaces between tags
    Dim i As Long, b As Boolean, l As Long
    a = Replace(a, Chr(13), "")
    a = Replace(a, Chr(10), "")
    a = treatInlineTags(a, True)
    For i = 1 To Len(a)
        Select Case Mid(a, i, 1)
        Case ">", "<"
            If i - l > 1 And l > 0 Then a = Left(a, l) & Right(a, Len(a) - i + 1)
            If i > 1 Then l = i
            If l > 0 Then b = True
        Case Is <> " "
            b = False
            l = 0
        End Select
    Next i
    CleanOf = a
End Function

Function Filler(n As Long, Optional Str As String = "0") As String
    If n > 0 Then Filler = Replace(Space$(n), " ", Str)
End Function
```

To test it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As String, b As String
    a = "<div class=""myclass""> " & Chr(13) & _
    "<ul><li>A</li>                   " & Chr(13) & _
    "<li>B</li><li>C</li>             " & _
    "</ul></div> <!-- just a comment -->" & _
    "<h2 class=""mytitle"">a title: inline and " & _
    "followed by a line break</h2>" & _
    "<div><ul><li><i class=""myitalic"">italic " & _
    "content: inline and NOT followed by a line break</i>" & _
    "</li></ul></div>"
    
    b = "<li><i class=""mylist""></i>a list <ul>" & _
    "<li>element 1</li><li>element 2</li><li>element 3</li></ul> " & _
    "</li><li>This <b>is bold</b> in an element list " & _
    "<a href=""#mydestination"">""with an href"" " & _
    "</a></li>"
    
    Debug.Print Chr(10) & "Test1 - input:" & Chr(10) & a
    Debug.Print Chr(10) & "Test1 - output:" & Chr(10) & ReadableHTML(a)
    
    Debug.Print Chr(10) & "Test2 - input:" & Chr(10) & b
    Debug.Print Chr(10) & "Test2 - output:" & Chr(10) & ReadableHTML(b)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the code did help me a lot but there is still a small quirk I cannot figure out. If you use the following test you'll the that the <ul> doesn't get where it should.

`str = "<li><i class=""icon-clock""></i>Durata 6 ore così distribuite:                    <ul>" & _
                        "<li>2 ore di guida in mattinata</li>" & _
                        "<li>2 ore di pausa per il pranzo</li>" & _
                        "<li>2 ore di guida nel pomeriggio</li>" & _
                    "</ul> " & _
                "</li>"`

Comment: Thank you for your edits. I made more changes and I think the code covers the case you mentioned now.

Comment: @RickD Thank you for the edits. Please don't forget to mark the answer if you think it does the trick.

Comment: @RickD I think you upvoted the answer, I meant [Accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out to the "Accepting the answer", this was my first question and I didn't not know how to behave. Many thanks, you were most helpful!